# Sticky div remain in top corner permanently

Tags: html, css

I have a 'Book Now' button that sticks to the top of the viewport at 10px gap.
The parent element has height of 100%, which means scrolling past 100%-worth of height makes the 'Book Now' div scroll out of view. [See here](https://levels.mintrain.co.uk).

How can I make the parent element 100% of the **full webpage** height, so the 'Book Now' div always sticks to the top?

HTML:

```
<div class="book font">
        <a href="index.html">BOOK NOW</a>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.book {
position: absolute;
height: 100%;
z-index: 100;
margin-top: 80px;
margin-right: 10px;
right: 0;
top: 0;
}

.book a {
    position: sticky;
    top: 10px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #1e1e1e;
    border: 4px solid #cfac44;
    background: #cfac44;
    padding: 10px 15px;
    transition: .2s;
    -webkit-transition: .2s;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem can be solved **without** `position: fixed`, keeping `position: sticky`.

Add `position: relative` for the `body` style:

```
body {
    ...
    position: relative;
}
```

And add `bottom: 0` for `.book` selector. This will stretch this `div` to the very bottom of the `body` tag:

```
.book {
    ...
    bottom: 0;
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for this! worked perfectly. I have a new problem, I had to add 'overflow-x: hidden' to html, body in order to stop the background video of the site from extending outside of the body. This has now interfered with the sticky div which no longer sticks! Any ideas?
edit: [link](https://levelsbarbers.co.uk)

Comment: Hello. Remove `overflow-x: hidden` from `html, body {}` and add for `body {}` only. Like this - https://ibb.co/98FwSTp.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply, this solves the position sticky but interferes with the background video! it still lets you scroll horizontally which I'm trying to fix

Comment: It worked for me and the video did not go beyond the window. Ok. I'm very busy right now, but as soon as the time comes, I'll look at the site again.

Comment: Hiya, yeah it works perfectly in Chrome, the problem is specific to Safari. And I've seen another thread on stack overflow with a supposed fix '-webkit-position: sticky' which doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
.book {
  position: absolute;
}
```

To:

```
.book {
  position: fixed;
}
```

And also remove `position: sticky;` from `.book a`

---

Codepen: https://codepen.io/manaskhandelwal1/pen/yLaROjq

Answer (score 0):

Change the position to fixed to both and adjust margin top and right like below code

```
.book {
   position: fixed;
   height: 100%;
   z-index: 100;
   margin-top: 30px;
   margin-right: 150px;
   right: 0;
   top: 0;
 }
```

a tag code

```
.book a {
     position: fixed;
     text-decoration: none;
     color: #1e1e1e;
     border: 4px solid #cfac44;
     background: #cfac44;
     padding: 10px 15px;
     transition: .2s;
     -webkit-transition: .2s;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I have change css, here below:

```css
book {
    position: fixed;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 100;
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-right: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
}

.book a {
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #1e1e1e;
    border: 4px solid #cfac44;
    background: #cfac44;
    padding: 10px 15px;
    transition: 0.2s;
    -webkit-transition: 0.2s;
}
```